# 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have ajax call where I process large data and then reload the page in ajax success. Ajax call is

```
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            async:false,
            url: 'URL',
            data: "",
            timeout:0,
            beforeSend:function(msgg){   
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "success")
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        window.location.reload();
                    },5000);
                }
            }
        });
```

but it gets 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT and ajax call never comes in success. I need manual refresh.

Comment: can you give your whole code?

Comment: Sorry it is not possible. Above ajax calls the url in php and after finish the task it returns success to ajax.

Comment: Don't use async false

Comment: I tried removing async false but same issue. I added alert("success") in success it shows message before process complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is to make more short calls to check status / retrieve data.

Here is the alternative if the above is not possible:

> Notice: This solution is not recommended for production use or high traffic scenarios, make sure this action is performed on an isolated server.

If using Apache Web Server 2.4, the `TimeOut` directive is by default set to 60 seconds.

For more details see [this article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout).

The web server will only keep the connection open for 60 seconds regardless the `max_execution_time`

While the `max_execution_time` in php.ini sets the execution time of php, the Apache `TimeOut` directive sets the maximum connection time.

Example:

- if php **max_execution_time** is 120 sec, but **TimeOut** is 30 sec - you will get a 504 error
- if php **max_execution_time** is 120 sec, but **TimeOut** is 300 sec - your script will execute for max 120 seconds, but your connection can stay alive for 300 seconds

If you didn't set any response code from php, PHP returns 200 if everything is OK, 500 if error occured.

When you get an unexpected HTTP Response code it's good to keep an eye on the web server too.

Comment: I believe 500 response codes are all server related - I haven't checked tho.

Answer (score 3):

`504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT` errors normally occur when your API Gateway URL is not responsive. It could be some kind of internal Gateway error.

Here are some steps to troubleshoot:

- Use a proxy like Postman to make the same exact request and see what the response is
- Make sure your path is correct
- If there are other requests that you make to the same gateway URL, maybe a GET request, try making those calls manually or using your code, to make sure the gateway is working fine
- If you have access to the Gateway, restart it (this is possible if you have Microservices architecture, and Dockerisation etc)

Comment: it is working fine. data is getting processed. If I use complete instead of success then complete gets called before all data is processed. in both the cases page reload is not working I have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

I think browser can not hold for long ajax call so I used ajax recall and processed data in parts. It solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found working solution posted by [#david-hoerster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237808/david-hoerster)

As he said, If your error event handler takes the three arguments (XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, and message) when a timeout happens, the status arg will be 'timeout'

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
        if(textstatus==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(textstatus);
        }
    }
});​
```

With [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3f9C/), you can test ajax calls -- it will wait 2 seconds before responding. I put the timeout set at 1 second, so it should error out and pass back a textstatus of 'timeout' to the error handler.